# Parsing (invalid) HTML from other website using PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

I'm trying to parse the following HTML from the following URL:

http://md5.rednoize.com/?q=fbade9e36a3f36d3d676c1b808451dd7

The code:

```
    $html = file_get_contents($url.$hash);
    $config = array(
      'clean' => 'yes',
      'output-html' => 'yes',
    );
    $tidy = tidy_parse_string($html, $config, 'utf8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($tidy);

    $result = $dom->getElementById('result');
```

However it is invalid:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [<a href='domdocument.loadhtml'>domdocument.loadhtml</a>]: ID switcher already defined in Entity, line: 128 in
```

Is there a way to still be able to parse it?

Comment: Maybe a silly remark, but cant you just put 'clean' => 'yes', to 'clean' => 'no',  ?

Comment: @Hans: Why would I want to do that?

Comment: What happens if you change `$dom->loadHTML($tidy);` to `$dom->loadHTML($tidy->value);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attempt to parse it after turning off strict error checking:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($tidy);
```